# How do these javascript obfuscators generate actual working code?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, reverse-engineering

There's [this one](http://utf-8.jp/public/jjencode.html) and [this one](http://utf-8.jp/public/aaencode.html) and they both generate completely unreadable code, one being more adorable than the other.

Now, I'm no expert in Javascript, but I fail to see how

```
ﾟωﾟﾉ= /｀ｍ´）ﾉ ~┻━┻   //*´∇｀*/ ['_']; o=(ﾟｰﾟ)  =_=3; c=(ﾟΘﾟ) =(ﾟｰﾟ)-(ﾟｰﾟ); (ﾟДﾟ) =(ﾟΘﾟ)= (o^_^o)/ (o^_^o);(ﾟДﾟ)={ﾟΘﾟ: '_' ,ﾟωﾟﾉ : ((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3) +'_') [ﾟΘﾟ] ,ﾟｰﾟﾉ :(ﾟωﾟﾉ+ '_')[o^_^o -(ﾟΘﾟ)] ,ﾟДﾟﾉ:((ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_')[ﾟｰﾟ] }; (ﾟДﾟ) [ﾟΘﾟ] =((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3) +'_') [c^_^o];(ﾟДﾟ) ['c'] = ((ﾟДﾟ)+'_') [ (ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)-(ﾟΘﾟ) ];(ﾟДﾟ) ['o'] = ((ﾟДﾟ)+'_') [ﾟΘﾟ];(ﾟoﾟ)=(ﾟДﾟ) ['c']+(ﾟДﾟ) ['o']+(ﾟωﾟﾉ +'_')[ﾟΘﾟ]+ ((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3) +'_') [ﾟｰﾟ] + ((ﾟДﾟ) +'_') [(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)]+ ((ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_') [ﾟΘﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_') [(ﾟｰﾟ) - (ﾟΘﾟ)]+(ﾟДﾟ) ['c']+((ﾟДﾟ)+'_') [(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)]+ (ﾟДﾟ) ['o']+((ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_') [ﾟΘﾟ];(ﾟДﾟ) ['_'] =(o^_^o) [ﾟoﾟ] [ﾟoﾟ];(ﾟεﾟ)=((ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_') [ﾟΘﾟ]+ (ﾟДﾟ) .ﾟДﾟﾉ+((ﾟДﾟ)+'_') [(ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟｰﾟ)]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_') [o^_^o -ﾟΘﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_') [ﾟΘﾟ]+ (ﾟωﾟﾉ +'_') [ﾟΘﾟ]; (ﾟｰﾟ)+=(ﾟΘﾟ); (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]='\\'; (ﾟДﾟ).ﾟΘﾟﾉ=(ﾟДﾟ+ ﾟｰﾟ)[o^_^o -(ﾟΘﾟ)];(oﾟｰﾟo)=(ﾟωﾟﾉ +'_')[c^_^o];(ﾟДﾟ) [ﾟoﾟ]='\"';(ﾟДﾟ) ['_'] ( (ﾟДﾟ) ['_'] (ﾟεﾟ+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ]+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ ((o^_^o) - (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (c^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) - (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) - (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (o^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (o^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (o^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ ((o^_^o) - (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) - (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ]) (ﾟΘﾟ)) ('_');
```

and

```
$=~[];$={___:++$,$$$$:(![]+"")[$],__$:++$,$_$_:(![]+"")[$],_$_:++$,$_$$:({}+"")[$],$$_$:($[$]+"")[$],_$$:++$,$$$_:(!""+"")[$],$__:++$,$_$:++$,$$__:({}+"")[$],$$_:++$,$$$:++$,$___:++$,$__$:++$};$.$_=($.$_=$+"")[$.$_$]+($._$=$.$_[$.__$])+($.$$=($.$+"")[$.__$])+((!$)+"")[$._$$]+($.__=$.$_[$.$$_])+($.$=(!""+"")[$.__$])+($._=(!""+"")[$._$_])+$.$_[$.$_$]+$.__+$._$+$.$;$.$$=$.$+(!""+"")[$._$$]+$.__+$._+$.$+$.$$;$.$=($.___)[$.$_][$.$_];$.$($.$($.$$+"\""+$.$_$_+(![]+"")[$._$_]+$.$$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+$.__+"(\\\"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$._$$+$.__+$.$_$_+$.$$__+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$._$$+"\\"+$.__$+$.__$+$.$$$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.$$_+$.$$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+$.$$$$+(![]+"")[$._$_]+$._$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.$$$+"\\\")"+"\"")())();
```

are actual valid javascript that do as expected. Seriously, run them. They're both `alert("StackOverflow")`. I could understand obfuscating some logic or string obfuscation, but there's no visible control statements. Is this obfuscator pulling some magic in the style of [The Language Which Shall Not Be Named](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck)? I'm happy with my code looking happy too, but I'm completely not understanding the magic behind it.

I've tried picking through the sourcecode of both pages, and they're as confusing for me as the code they generate.

How does this work?

Comment: All they are doing is using unicode strings or punctuation marks for variables (side note: those are also probably valid Perl programs)

Comment: FYI: `~[]` is "not array", and evaluates to `-1`.

Comment: As for "no visible control statements" your tiny bit of source code didn't have any.  While these may work, the apparant blowup factor in size seems incredible.  It is full of dumb obfuscations (the second one has lots of pointless '...+""' e.g, concatenate an empty string).  This may obfuscate your code, but I'd guess you would not want to run a big piece of javascript processed by this; it would likely be very slow.

Comment: The first one is using lots of unconventional variable evaluations, too. For example, after running the code, `o` evaluates to `3`, as do `_` and `(o^_^o)`. Dig deep enough and I'll bet the whole statement is a clever way of referencing different members of the `(ﾟДﾟ)` object.

Comment: @IraBaxter Even when I add control statements, they don't actually really show up inside the obfuscated code.

Comment: They also trivially exceed the call stack size, so don't actually. They are cute toys though

Comment: I wrote about these types of obfuscation a few month ago in my blog. Here's the link if you are interested : http://holyvier.blogspot.com/2011/10/javascript-obfuscation-introduction.html

Comment: @HoLyVieR: http://holyvier.blogspot.com/2011/09/javascript-obfuscation-part-2-strings.html is probably the best part of your stuff, I learned the most from that. Thank you for sharing your post!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As my javascript excerise of the day, a line by line break down. Note I generated mine with `alert("Hello")`

```
$ = ~[];   // var $ = -1
$ = 
    {
    ___ : ++$,              // ++(-1) == 0
    $$$$:(![]+"")[$],       // ![] == false, false + "" == "false", "false"[0] == "f"
    __$:++$,                // ++(0) == 1    
    $_$_:(![]+"")[$],       // ![] == false, false + "" == "false", "false"[1] == "a"
    _$_:++$,                // ++(1) == 2
    $_$$:({}+"")[$],        // {} + "" == "[object Object]", "[object Object]"[2] == "b"
    $$_$:($[$]+"")[$],      // 2[2] == undefined + "" == "undefined", "undefined"[2] == "d"
    _$$:++$,                // ++(2) == 3
    $$$_:(!""+"")[$],       // !"" == true + "" == "true", "true"[3] == "e"
    $__:++$,                // ++(3) == 4
    $_$:++$,                // ++(4) == 5
    $$__:({}+"")[$],        // ({} + "") == [object Object]", "[object Object]"[5] == "c"
    $$_:++$,                // ++(5) == 6
    $$$:++$,                // ++(6) == 7
    $___:++$,               // ++(7) == 8
    $__$:++$                // ++(8) == 9
};

$.$_ = 
    ($.$_=$+"")[$.$_$] +        // "[object Object]"[5] == "c" +  (also $.$_ = "[object Object]")
    ($._$=$.$_[$.__$]) +        // "[object Object]"[1] == "o" + (also $._$ = "o")
    ($.$$=($.$+"")[$.__$]) +    // $.$+"" == "undefined", "undefined"[1] == "n" + (also $.$$ = "n")
    ((!$)+"")[$._$$] +          // !$ == false, false+"" == "false", "false"[3] == "s" +
    ($.__=$.$_[$.$$_]) +        // "[object Object]"[6] == "t" (also $.__ = "t") +
    ($.$=(!""+"")[$.__$]) +     // !"" == true, true + "" == "true", "true"[2] == "r" +(also $.$="r")
    ($._=(!""+"")[$._$_]) +     // !"" == true, true + "" == "true", "true"[3] == "u" +(also $._="u")
    $.$_[$.$_$] +               // "[object Object]"[5] == "c" +
    $.__ +                      // "t" +
    $._$ +                      // "o" +
    $.$;                        // "r"

// $.$_ = "constructor"

$.$$ = 
    $.$ +                       // "r" +
    (!""+"")[$._$$] +           // "true"[3] == "e" +
    $.__ +                      // "t" +
    $._  +                      // "u" +
    $.$ +                       // "r" +
    $.$$;                       // "n" 
// $.$$ = "return"

$.$ = ($.___)[$.$_][$.$_];      // (0)["constructor"]["constructor"]
// $.$ = Function

// This is the part that changes when you change the input string.

$.$(                            // Function( 
    $.$(                        // Function (
        $.$$ +                  // "return"+
        "\""+                   // '"' +
        $.$_$_ +                // "a" + 
        (![]+"")[$._$_]+        // "l" + 
        $.$$$_+                 // "e" + 
        "\\"+                   // "\" +            
        $.__$+                  // "1" + 
        $.$$_+                  // "6" + 
        $._$_+                  // "2" +   (note '\162' = 'r')   
        $.__+                   // "t" + 
        "(\\\"\\"+              // '(\"\' +    
        $.__$+                  // 1 + 
        $.__$+                  // 1 + 
        $.___+                  // 0 +     (note '\110' = 'H')    
        $.$$$_+                 // e + 
        (![]+"")[$._$_]+        // "false"[2] == "l", "l" + 
        (![]+"")[$._$_]+        // "false"[2] == "l", "l" + 
        $._$+                   // "o" + 
        "\\\")"+                // '\")' +
        "\""                    // '"''
    )()                         // invoke
)();                            // invoke
```

am not i am is pretty much spot on, it creates a string and then invokes it.

*Edit – and I don't have time to decode the other version, but I imagine its doing something similar, but with non latin characters.*

Answer (score 32):

What fun!  Here's my go at it.  Basically what is happening here is a bunch of numbers and strings are being assigned to variables.  Those variables are being concatenated to form an encoded string.  That encoded string is decoded to form a string of JavaScript code.  That code is set as the body of a function, which is then executed.

Let's take it line by line:

**Line 1:**

```js
ﾟωﾟﾉ = /｀ｍ´）ﾉ ~┻━┻   //*´∇｀*/['_'];
```

`ﾟωﾟﾉ` - a global variable
`/｀ｍ´）ﾉ ~┻━┻   /` - a regular expression
`/*´∇｀*/` - a multi-line comment
`['_']` - get the property `_` of the regular expression.

Since a RegExp does not have a `_` property, the variable `ﾟωﾟﾉ` contains the value `undefined`.

**Line 2:**

```js
o = (ﾟｰﾟ) = _ = 3;
```

Define the variables `o`, `ﾟｰﾟ`, and `_`, and set each of their values to `3`.

**Line 3:**

```js
c = (ﾟΘﾟ) = (ﾟｰﾟ) - (ﾟｰﾟ);
```

Define the variables `c` and `ﾟΘﾟ` and set their values to `0`. (`ﾟｰﾟ` is `3`, so `(ﾟｰﾟ) - (ﾟｰﾟ)` is the same as `ﾟｰﾟ - ﾟｰﾟ` is the same as `3 - 3`.  Now `c` and `ﾟΘﾟ` both contain `1`;

**Line 4:**

```js
(ﾟДﾟ) = (ﾟΘﾟ) = (o ^ _ ^ o) / (o ^ _ ^ o);
```

Define the variable `ﾟДﾟ` and redefine the variable `ﾟΘﾟ`.  `^` is the [bitwise XOR operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ece515h6(VS.94).aspx) and `o` and `_` are both `3`.
`o ^ _ ^ o` is the same as `3 ^ 3 ^ 3`.
`3 ^ 3` is `0`, `3 ^ 0` is `3`.
Then `3 / 3` is `1`.
`ﾟДﾟ` and `ﾟΘﾟ` both now contain `1`.

**Line 5:**

```js
(ﾟДﾟ) = { ﾟΘﾟ: '_', ﾟωﾟﾉ: ((ﾟωﾟﾉ == 3) + '_')[ﾟΘﾟ], ﾟｰﾟﾉ: (ﾟωﾟﾉ + '_')[o ^ _ ^ o - (ﾟΘﾟ)], ﾟДﾟﾉ: ((ﾟｰﾟ == 3) + '_')[ﾟｰﾟ] };
```

With line breaks and indentation:

```js
(ﾟДﾟ) = {
    ﾟΘﾟ: '_',
    ﾟωﾟﾉ: ((ﾟωﾟﾉ == 3) + '_')[ﾟΘﾟ],
    ﾟｰﾟﾉ: (ﾟωﾟﾉ + '_')[o ^ _ ^ o - (ﾟΘﾟ)],
    ﾟДﾟﾉ: ((ﾟｰﾟ == 3) + '_')[ﾟｰﾟ]
};
```

Redefine `ﾟДﾟ` as an object literal, with properties `ﾟΘﾟ`, `ﾟωﾟﾉ`, `ﾟｰﾟﾉ`, and `ﾟДﾟﾉ`.
`ﾟДﾟ.ﾟΘﾟ` is "_".
`ﾟДﾟ.ﾟωﾟﾉ` is `((undefined == 3) + "_")[1]` which is `"false_"[1]` which is `"a"`.
`ﾟДﾟ.ﾟｰﾟﾉ` is `(undefined + "_")[3 ^ 3 ^ 3 - 1]` which is `"undefined_"[2]` which is `"d"`.
`ﾟДﾟ.ﾟДﾟﾉ` is `((3 == 3) + "_")[3]` which is `"true_"[3]` which is `"u"`.

**Line 6:**

```js
(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟΘﾟ] = ((ﾟωﾟﾉ == 3) + '_')[c ^ _ ^ o];
```

Is the same as:

```js
ﾟДﾟ.ﾟΘﾟ = ((undefined == 3) + "_")[1 ^ 3 ^ 3];
```

Which is the same as:

```js
ﾟДﾟ.ﾟΘﾟ = "false_"[1];
```

So `ﾟДﾟ.ﾟΘﾟ` is `"a"`.

**Lines 7 - 16:**

And so it continues, assigning strings and numbers to variables and object properties.  Until the last line:

**Line 17:**

```js
(ﾟДﾟ)['_']((ﾟДﾟ)['_'](ﾟεﾟ + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ] + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + (ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + (ﾟｰﾟ) + ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + ((o ^ _ ^ o) + (o ^ _ ^ o)) + ((o ^ _ ^ o) - (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + ((o ^ _ ^ o) + (o ^ _ ^ o)) + (ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (c ^ _ ^ o) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟｰﾟ) + ((o ^ _ ^ o) - (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ) + (c ^ _ ^ o) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + (ﾟｰﾟ) + ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ)) + ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o ^ _ ^ o)) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟｰﾟ) + (c ^ _ ^ o) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ) + ((o ^ _ ^ o) - (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + (ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + ((o ^ _ ^ o) + (o ^ _ ^ o)) + ((o ^ _ ^ o) + (o ^ _ ^ o)) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + (ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + ((o ^ _ ^ o) - (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (o ^ _ ^ o) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + (ﾟｰﾟ) + (o ^ _ ^ o) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + ((o ^ _ ^ o) + (o ^ _ ^ o)) + ((o ^ _ ^ o) - (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (ﾟΘﾟ) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + ((o ^ _ ^ o) + (o ^ _ ^ o)) + (c ^ _ ^ o) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + ((o ^ _ ^ o) + (o ^ _ ^ o)) + (ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟｰﾟ) + ((o ^ _ ^ o) - (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (ﾟΘﾟ) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ])(ﾟΘﾟ))('_');
```

By this time, we have the following variables:

```js
ﾟωﾟﾉ    // undefined
o       // 3
ﾟｰﾟ     // 4
_       // 3
c       // 0
ﾟΘﾟ     // 1
ﾟДﾟ     /* {
            "1": "f",
            ﾟΘﾟ: "_",
            ﾟωﾟﾉ: "a",
            ﾟｰﾟﾉ: "d",
            ﾟДﾟﾉ: "e",
            c: "c",
            o: "o",
            return: "\\",
            ﾟΘﾟﾉ: "b",
            constructor: "\"",
            _: Function
        } */
ﾟoﾟ     // "constructor"
ﾟεﾟ     // "return"
oﾟｰﾟo   // "u"
```

That line is mostly one big string concatenation.  We can make it *slightly* more readable by removing the unnecessary parentheses and adding line breaks:

```js
ﾟДﾟ['_'](
    ﾟДﾟ['_'](
        ﾟεﾟ + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟoﾟ] + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ﾟｰﾟ + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        (ﾟｰﾟ + ﾟΘﾟ) + 
        ﾟｰﾟ + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ﾟｰﾟ + 
        (ﾟｰﾟ + ﾟΘﾟ) + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ((o ^ _ ^ o) + (o ^ _ ^ o)) + 
        ((o ^ _ ^ o) - ﾟΘﾟ) + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ((o ^ _ ^ o) + (o ^ _ ^ o)) + 
        ﾟｰﾟ + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        (ﾟｰﾟ + ﾟΘﾟ) + 
        (c ^ _ ^ o) + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟｰﾟ + 
        ((o ^ _ ^ o) - ﾟΘﾟ) + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        (c ^ _ ^ o) + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ﾟｰﾟ + 
        (ﾟｰﾟ + ﾟΘﾟ) + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        (ﾟｰﾟ + ﾟΘﾟ) + 
        ﾟｰﾟ + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        (ﾟｰﾟ + ﾟΘﾟ) + 
        ﾟｰﾟ + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        (ﾟｰﾟ + ﾟΘﾟ) + 
        (ﾟｰﾟ + (o ^ _ ^ o)) + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        (ﾟｰﾟ + ﾟΘﾟ) + 
        ﾟｰﾟ + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟｰﾟ + 
        (c ^ _ ^ o) + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ((o ^ _ ^ o) - ﾟΘﾟ) + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ﾟｰﾟ + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ((o ^ _ ^ o) + (o ^ _ ^ o)) + 
        ((o ^ _ ^ o) + (o ^ _ ^ o)) + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ﾟｰﾟ + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ((o ^ _ ^ o) - ﾟΘﾟ) + 
        (o ^ _ ^ o) + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ﾟｰﾟ + 
        (o ^ _ ^ o) + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ((o ^ _ ^ o) + (o ^ _ ^ o)) + 
        ((o ^ _ ^ o) - ﾟΘﾟ) + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        (ﾟｰﾟ + ﾟΘﾟ) + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ((o ^ _ ^ o) + (o ^ _ ^ o)) + 
        (c ^ _ ^ o) + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ((o ^ _ ^ o) + (o ^ _ ^ o)) + 
        ﾟｰﾟ + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        ﾟｰﾟ + 
        ((o ^ _ ^ o) - ﾟΘﾟ) + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟεﾟ] + 
        (ﾟｰﾟ + ﾟΘﾟ) + 
        ﾟΘﾟ + 
        ﾟДﾟ[ﾟoﾟ]
    )(ﾟΘﾟ)
)("_");
```

The value of that concatenated string is:

```js
return"\141\154\145\162\164\50\42\110\145\154\154\157\54\40\112\141\166\141\123\143\162\151\160\164\42\51"
```

So, replacing all the variables with literals, we end up with the following JavaScript which gets executed on that last line:

```js
Function(Function("return\"\\141\\154\\145\\162\\164\\50\\42\\110\\145\\154\\154\\157\\54\\40\\112\\141\\166\\141\\123\\143\\162\\151\\160\\164\\42\\51\"")(1))("_")
```

Breaking that line down, in the middle we see the concatenated string is passed to a `Function` constructor, making the string the function body:

```js
Function("return\"\\141\\154\\145\\162\\164\\50\\42\\110\\145\\154\\154\\157\\54\\40\\112\\141\\166\\141\\123\\143\\162\\151\\160\\164\\42\\51\"")
```

So, that string is evaluated as JavaScript, and the `Function` constructor returns this function:

```js
function () {
    return"\141\154\145\162\164\50\42\110\145\154\154\157\54\40\112\141\166\141\123\143\162\151\160\164\42\51";
}
```

That function is immediately executed:

```js
Function("return\"\\141\\154\\145\\...\\51\"")(1)
```

And returns the string:

```js
alert("Hello, JavaScript")
```

Hey, that looks like JavaScript!  But it's not yet.  It's just a string.  But that string is passed to another `Function` constructor, giving us a function that executes the string as JavaScript:

```js
Function("alert(\"Hello, JavaScript\")")
```

That is the same as:

```js
function () {
    alert("Hello, JavaScript");
}
```

That function is immediately executed:

```js
Function("alert(\"Hello, JavaScript\")")("_")
```

And our unobfuscated code is finally called.

Comment: I wish I could select this as correct too. Nice work as well!

Answer (score 12):

Type `$` into the console (after running the code), and expand the object. You can then more easily analyze it.

[image]

They're grabbing enough words/characters using sneaky means, and referencing them in the $ object, then using them to build the program and `eval`ing likely in a `Function(...)()` call.

So it should boil down to...

```
Function('alert("StackOverflow")')();
```

...or something similar.

---

Beginning to unwind it, ...

```
$=~[];  // -1

$={
  0:++$,         //  0
  f:(![]+"")[$], // "f", (![]+"") is "false", and [$] gives index 0, or "f"
  1:++$,         //  1
  a:(![]+"")[$], // "a", (![]+"") is "false", and [$] gives index 1, or "a"
  2:++$,         //  2
  b:({}+"")[$],  // "b", ({}+"") is "[object Object]", and [$] gives index 2, or "b"
  d:($[$]+"")[$],// "d", ($[$]+"") is "undefined", and [$] gives index 2, or "d"
  3:++$,         //  3
  e:(!""+"")[$], // "e", (!""+"") is "true", and [$] gives index 3, or "e"
  4:++$,         //  4
  5:++$,         //  5
  c:({}+"")[$],  // "c", ({}+"") is "[object Object]", and [$] gives index 5, or "c"
  6:++$,         //  6
  7:++$,         //  7
  8:++$,         //  8
  9:++$          //  9
};

$.constructor=($.constructor=$+"")[$[5]]+($.o=$.constructor[$[1]])+($.return=($.$+"")[$[1]])+((!$)+"")[$[3]]+($.t=$.constructor[$[6]])+($.$=(!""+"")[$[1]])+($.u=(!""+"")[$[2]])+$.constructor[$[5]]+$.t+$.o+$.$;
$.return=$.$+(!""+"")[$[3]]+$.t+$.u+$.$+$.return;
$.$=($[0])[$.constructor][$.constructor];
$.$($.$($.return+"\""+$.a+(![]+"")[$[2]]+$.e+"\\"+$[1]+$[6]+$[2]+$.t+"(\\\"\\"+$[1]+$[2]+$[3]+$.t+$.a+$.c+"\\"+$[1]+$[5]+$[3]+"\\"+$[1]+$[1]+$[7]+"\\"+$[1]+$[6]+$[6]+$.e+"\\"+$[1]+$[6]+$[2]+$.f+(![]+"")[$[2]]+$.o+"\\"+$[1]+$[6]+$[7]+"\\\")"+"\"")())();
```

Then...

```
$.constructor=($.constructor=$+"")[5]+($.o=$.constructor[1])+($.return=($.$+"")[1])+((!$)+"")[3]+($.t=$.constructor[6])+($.$=(!""+"")[1])+($.u=(!""+"")[2])+$.constructor[5]+$.t+$.o+$.$;
$.return=$.$+(!""+"")[3]+$.t+$.u+$.$+$.return;
$.$=(0)[$.constructor][$.constructor];
$.$($.$($.return+"\""+$.a+(![]+"")[2]+$.e+"\\"+$[1]+$[6]+$[2]+$.t+"(\\\"\\"+$[1]+$[2]+$[3]+$.t+$.a+$.c+"\\"+$[1]+$[5]+$[3]+"\\"+$[1]+$[1]+$[7]+"\\"+$[1]+$[6]+$[6]+$.e+"\\"+$[1]+$[6]+$[2]+$.f+(![]+"")[2]+$.o+"\\"+$[1]+$[6]+$[7]+"\\\")"+"\"")())();
```

...eh, lost interest.

Answer (score 10):

Since every other answer are only analyses of the code you have given, I will expand on how you can generate those by yourself (without tools). I believe this will give you a better overview of how it works.

Most of these obfuscation are based on few features/principles of JavaScript. The first one is that the variable name can use **Unicode** Letter ([Lu](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm), [Ll](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ll/list.htm), [Lt](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lt/list.htm), [Lm](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lm/list.htm), [Lo](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lo/list.htm), [Nl](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nl/list.htm)) and **Unicode** Number ([Nd](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm)). In the first example you have given, the character may look like symbols, but they are Unicode letter or Unicode number.

The second one is that adding an empty string to anything in JavaScript will cast it to a string. If you also use the fact that strings are an array-like structure in JavaScript, you can easily make stuff like : `(false+"")[0]`, which can also be written has `(!1+"")[0]`. From that point you can compose your own string letter by letter.

The third one is that every object property can be accessed with the `[]` notation. For example : `window["alert"]("test")` is the same as `window.alert("test")`. If you mix that with the previous paragraph, I think you can easily see where it can go.

The only thing we are missing to get started is either a reference to `window` or `Function`. The other answers, already provide you a way to access `Function` which can be use like `eval`. To get `window` tough, the easiest way is to leak it through `Array.concat` this way :

```
t= [].concat;
a = t()[0]; // "a" now contains window
```

Once you have `window`, you can either use `window["eval"]` or call directly `window["alert"]`.

That's all for the basis of how you actually do these kind of obfuscation. The rest is just variation of the previous points. If you want additional information, I did a couple of blog post about this, you can find them here : http://holyvier.blogspot.com/2011/10/javascript-obfuscation-introduction.html